# Erro na requisição user_timeline da API do Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter-api

Estou passando uma dificuldade grande em achar algum material que explique como uso a API do Twitter para **pegar as publicações mais recentes de determinado usuário e exibí-las em meu website.**

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) cheguei a seguinte requisição:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={{nome}}
```

Onde `{{nome}}` é o nome único de identificação do usuário.

Porém, o resultado nunca muda:

```
{
  - errors: [
      - {
            message: "Bad Authentication data",
            code: 215
        }
    ]
}
```

No código, geralmente eu uso a função `$.getJSON()` do jQuery, mas acredito que não iria mudar o cenário.

Acho que não é tão simples quanto pensei que fosse. **Quais os passos que devo seguir até chegar no objetivo citado no começo da dúvida?**

Comment: Primeiro você precisa [autenticar sua app](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) ([ou usuário](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens)) na API.

Answer (score 2):

[Nesse mesmo link da documentação oficial](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline), há uma coluna a direita com a seguinte linha:

> Authentication:   **Required**

Você consegue usar outra linguagem para fazer estas requisições ou precisa fazer com JavaScript? Se você pode fazer isso no *backend*, existem vários *wrappers* prontos pra facilitar sua vida, dá uma olhada [nestas *libraries*](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).

Se não, o que você precisa basicamente é autenticar através do método OAuth.

Comment: Não tem condições de usar alguma linguagem de back-end. E é justamente como pegar essa autorização com JavaScript que eu quero desenvolver. Tem como me ajudar?